# Button with multiple functions (swift, Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, button

H, I would like to have one button that has multiple functions. I am making a choose your own adventure app, fyi. I would like to have a button that is the "Begin game" button, that, when clicked changes not only text(I have that worked out) but also changes function. I want it to keep advancing the story. The "story" is a label that is in the top half of the screen, that I would like to change when the button is pressed. I can have it change once, but I would like it to change when the button is pressed after the first time. How would I go about doing this? By the way I am a newcomer to programming especially swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Message: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RevealButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func RButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        Message?.hidden = false
        Message?.text = "Welcome! This is going to be an adventure!"
        RevealButton?.setTitle("Wake up?" , forState:UIControlState.Normal )
        func WakeUp(sender: AnyObject) {
            RevealButton?.setTitle("Walk Outside" , forState:UIControlState.Normal )  
        }       
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Before this comment is ultimately deleted, I'm going to suggest you look into going through some beginner programming exercises. There's a ton of info out there, so learn some basics before diving in over your head.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the target for the button before adding another. This is done with the removeTarget and addTarget methods:

```
func removeTarget(_ target: AnyObject?,
       action action: Selector,
 forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)

func addTarget(_ target: AnyObject?,
      action action: Selector,
forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)
```

For more, see Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make it as complicated as stated by Markk. If you use different triggers then thats fine too. For example you could make one `IBAction` using `touchUpInside` and another one with `touchUpOutside` or maybe `touchDown`